# How do you do *alternating* objects on a curve with geometery nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

There's plenty of tutorials about how to instance a single object on a curve using geometry nodes, but I can't seem to find a way to *alternate* them - instance two cylinders, then a sphere, then two cylinders again, etc.

I've been trying to make it work with the Index input, then using modulo & comparison, but I don't know how to get it to actually make the switch since the Switch node doesn't want to take the output from the comparison node.

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

node setup:

[image]

result:

[image]

Modulo 3 gives 0,1,2,0,1,2 and so on.

So just compare with < 2 -> then the switch decides which object will be chosen.

In the collection "objects" are the sphere and the cylinder. Depending on your order in the collection you might have to change 0 and 1 in the switch node.